# Checkbox appears and disappears after multiple clicks

Tags: python, checkbox, kivy

What should I do to make the checkbox never disappear when I click on it several times?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<MyWidget>:
    CheckBox:
        active: root.odrzuc
        group: "Zone "

    CheckBox:
        active: root.decyduj
        group: "Zone "

''')

class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    odrzuc = BooleanProperty(False)
    decyduj = BooleanProperty(True)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

I try a lot of method and I don't know what I can do.

Comment: I tried your code, and it works fine. Could it be a broken kivy installation?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: yeah @Reverse i tried the code it the problem still persists, im running kivy 1.9.1

Comment: Nice that you noticed what i meant @Joey daniel darko. 
Does anyone know what is causing the problem?